# How to embed a swf file in an iphone application

Tags: ios, iphone

I need to display an swf file in an iphone application. Is it possible to include it in UIImageView or UIWebView

Comment: just use air,the swf can not play in UIWebView or UIImageVIew

Comment: convert the swf file to other video format and play it in MPMoviePlayerController

Answer (score 0):

Flash is not supported by iPhone, iPad and any other iOS device.